# Troubleshooting javascript for Stripe

Tags: javascript, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm using Devise 3 and Stripe 1.8.4 in a Rails 4 app. I'd appreciate if someone could look over my javascript. I have an error that I haven't been able to find. Its been eating me up for the last few days. I'm pretty sure it is a javascript error since the error from stripe is "Empty string given for card". I'm assuming that the card details are not being submitted because something is up with the javascript. Thank you in advance for your help.

My form is as follows:

```
 <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url =>  
registration_path(resource_name), :id => 'payment-form', method: :post)  do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

  <!-- Create Account -->  
  <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.input :first_name, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => "First Name", label:false %>
    <%= f.input :last_name, :placeholder => "Last Name", label:false, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :email, :placeholder => "Email Address", label:false, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :password, :placeholder => "Password", label:false, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Password Confirmation", label:false, :required => true %>
  <!-- Terms -->  
    <%= f.input :terms, as: :boolean, label: 'I agree to the terms of service.' %>
    <%= f.input :autorenew, as: :boolean, label: 'Automatically renew my account each year.' %> 

  </div>

  <!-- Payment Information --> 

        <span class="payment-errors"></span>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-8 columns">
            <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" placeholder="Credit Card Number"/>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-3 columns">
            <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" placeholder="CVC Code"/>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-4 columns">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="small-5 columns">
                <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month" placeholder ="MM"/>
              </div>
              <div class="small-6 columns">
                <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year" placeholder="YYYY"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

         <div class="row">
          <div class="small-4 columns">
            <input type="text" size="10" data-stripe="coupon" placeholder="Coupon Code"/>
          </div>
        </div>

     <%= f.input :stripe_token, as: :hidden  %>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Subscribe", :class => "button radius" %>
      </div>

  <% end %>
```

The javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function($){
Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>');

$('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
  var form = $('#payment-form');
  form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
  Stripe.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler);
  return false;
});

 function stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
   var form = $('#payment-form');
   if (response.error) {
   // Show the errors on the form
     form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
     form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
   } else {
   // token contains id, last4, and card type
     var token = response.id;
   // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
     form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
   // and submit
     form.get(0).submit();
   }
};
```

});

Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Tried changing function to var, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question again on this. Turns out there is nothing wrong with the code. This code wasn't working in my view, but if I move the js to application.js the transaction with Stripe works perfectly. Not sure why though.